# Solving a line intercept equation

Tags: geometry, line, cartesian-coordinates

What is  A and B so that the line Ay = Bx + 1 passes through points (1, 3) and (5,13) in the Cartesian plane?

I have been trying to solve it using the slope intercept equation to no avail. This is taken from Dale Hoffman's Contemprary Calculus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com and when you post it there, you need to include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Just substitute the two pairs of XY values in and you have a pair of 2-variable simultaneous equations. *Literally* the simplest type of simultaneous equation. No need for slopes and intercepts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would reorder to get canonical form,

```
y = (B/A) * x + (1/A) = m * x + b
```

Now we find slope (m):

```
m = dy / dx = (13 - 3) / (5 - 1) = 2.5
```

sub in to find b:

```
3 = 2.5 * 1 + b

b = 0.5
```

Now sub back to find the values you want,

```
b = 0.5 = 1 / A

A = 2

m = 2.5 = B / 2

B = 5
```